# How to show decimal point only when it's not a whole number?

Tags: python

I have Googled, but couldn't find a proper answer to this.

Let's say we have floats and we get their averages. Their averages are like this:

```
3.5
2.5
5
7
```

So we've got 4 numbers *(who are not in a list anymore)*. Two numbers with a decimal and two whole numbers.

What I want to do is, to print these numbers and keep them like this. My problem is, though, that when I use `%.1f`, it makes 5.0 and 7.0 from 5 and 7, while I want to keep them as they are *(so keep them as a whole number)*.

So I'd like to print them exactly as they are, but I don't know how. Float adds `decimal` points to whole numbers. Converting them to an `int`, removes the needed decimals.

Both options are not what I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit: the relevant code, as asked:**

```
# I have a list of numbers and I am calculating their average and rounding them first.
get_numbers = map(float, line[-1])
average_numbers = sum(get_numbers) / len(get_numbers)
rounded_numbers= round(average_numbers * 2) / 2

# So now, I've got the numbers: 3.5, 2.5, 5, 7

print "The numbers are: %.1f" % (rounded_numbers)
```

Comment: cast them to integers

Comment: Please clarify - are your 4 numbers actually `float, float, int, int`, or are they all floats?  Note that the `is_integer` solution won't work if your input is actually an int, and the `format` solutions won't work if all your inputs are actually floats.

Comment: They are all floats. Some of them rounded, some not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use floats' [is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method. It returns `True` if a float can be represented as an integer (in other words, if it is of the form `X.0`):

```
li = [3.5, 2.5, 5.0, 7.0]

print([int(num) if float(num).is_integer() else num for num in li])
>> [3.5, 2.5, 5, 7]
```

**EDIT**

After OP added their code:

Instead of using list comprehension like in my original example above, you should use the same logic with your calculated average:

```
get_numbers = map(float, line[-1])  # assuming line[-1] is a list of numbers
average_numbers = sum(get_numbers) / len(get_numbers)
average = round(average_numbers * 2) / 2
average = int(average) if float(average).is_integer() else average
print average  # this for example will print 3 if the average is 3.0 or
               # the actual float representation.
```

Comment: This throws an "int object has no attribute 'is_integer'" error when using the data from the OP.  Although its redundant, maybe change `num.is_integer()` to `float(num).is_integer()`?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I believe OPs inputs are all floats since otherwise they wouldn't have this problem to begin with, but I will add `float(...)` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Honestly, I believe you're right.  The float conversion shouldn't be necessary.  But it makes sure you can't get an error, so thanks for adding it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it says: "'float' object is not iterable"

Comment: @Siyah You only have a single number. My answer assumes you have a list of numbers.

Comment: Well, I have four lists and I calculate the average number of the numbers in those lists... So I've got four numbers who are not in a list anymore...

Comment: I can't print it anyway else?

Comment: @Siyah Print it normally (`print average`), with `{}` and format or `%`.

Comment: Thanks mate! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous answer:

```
[int(i) if int(i) == i else i for i in li]
```

Or:

```
[int(i) if not i % 1 else i for i in li]
```

Answer (score -3):

Technically, if you have floats and get their averages, you SHOULD get floats back. But if you just want to print them, the following should work well:

```
print('{} {} {} {}'.format(3.5, 2.5, 5, 7))
```