# Displaying to two decimal points in Python 3.x... but also without these decimals, if applicable - how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

In Python 3.8 I'm trying to get a float value to display as follows:

- If the number has more than 2 decimal points, it should be rounded to
  2 decimal points.
- If the number has one decimal point, it should
  display as only one decimal point.
- If the number has no decimal
  points, it should not display with a decimal point at all.

I'm aware of "round".  If I have this program:

```
print ('input a number')
chuu = float(input())
chuu = round(chuu,2)
print (chuu)
```

- Input 3.141 results in 3.14 (good)
- Input 3.1 results in 3.1 (good)
- Input 3 results in 3.0 (bad, I want 3)

I'm also aware that I can do this:

```
print ('input a number')
chuu = float(input())
print('{0:.2f}'.format(chuu))
```

This doesn't get what I want either:

- Input 3.141 results in 3.14 (good)
- Input 3.1 results in 3.10 (bad, I want 3.1)
- Input 3 results in 3.00 (bad, I want 3)

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Doesn’t sound too hard to code - please edit your own attempt to solve this into your question.

Comment: Um... I already have two attempts there?

Comment: Er... I think you have simply shown what the standard library `round()` and formatted printing do, and demonstrated that they can't solve your problem, which is fine as far as it goes - but I don't see *any* attempt to then write some code perhaps around those functions to *actually* solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show decimal point only when it's not a whole number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767344/how-to-show-decimal-point-only-when-its-not-a-whole-number)

Comment: @Georgy yes, but I like the answer by Snehil below better, it's effectively similar but simpler and more erudite, certainly the easiest to understand.  It's the sort of answer I feel silly for not thinking of myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply do this

```
print ('input a number')
chuu = float(input())
chuu = round(chuu,2)
if int(chuu)==chuu:
    print(int(chuu))
else:
    print(chuu)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the general format types of string formatting.

```
print('input a number')
chuu = float(input())
print('{:g}'.format(round(chuu, 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this fits!

```py
chuu = 4.1111             #works for 4, 4.1111, 4.1

print(chuu if str(chuu).find('.')==-1 else round(chuu,2))
```

### Edit:

@Mark very accurately pointed out a potential flaw in the above approach.

Here's a modified approach that supports many possibilities including what @mark pointed out.

```py
print(chu if type(chu)!=float else ('{0:.2f}' if(len(str(chu).split('.')[-1])>=2) else '{0:.1f}').format(round(chu,2)))
```

Caters to all these possibilities:

```py
#Demonstration
li = [0.00005,1.100005,1.00001,0.00001,1.11111,1.111,1.01,1.1,0.0000,5,1000]
meth1 = lambda chu: chu if type(chu)!=float else ('{0:.2f}' if(len(str(chu).split('.')[-1])>=2) else '{0:.1f}').format(round(chu,2))

print(*map(meth1,li))

output
0.00 1.10 1.00 0.00 1.11 1.11 1.01 1.1 0.0 5 1000
```

[image: Profile]

### Note: Doesn't work with negative numbers

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing something with string manipulation where I could convert to a string, look at the last two digits etc... but I was after something more elegant and Pythonic than this.

Comment: i have made some edits, see if this is what you are looking for. It doesnt involve a function and its pythonic.

Comment: What does this do for `0.00005`?

Comment: @mark thanks for pointing that out, i hv made changes to the answer, however even this approach would not work with negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it for printing, the following works.

```
from decimal import Decimal

print('Input a number: ')
chuu = float(input())

print(Decimal(str(round(chuu, 2))).normalize())
```

However, this will turn numbers like 3.0 into just 3. (Not clear if you wanted that behavior or not)

Comment: Yep this works nicely, and will do because I only want to print rather than calculate.  However prefer not to import a module if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
def specialRound(num):
    #check if has decimals
    intForm = int(num)
    if(num==intForm):
        return intForm
    TDNumber = round(num,2) #Two decimals
    ODNumber = round(num,1) #One decimal
    if(TDNumber>ODNumber):
        return TDNumber
    return ODNumber

print(specialRound(3.1415))
print(specialRound(3.10))
print(specialRound(3))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is good, but a little involved, I didn't want to add functions to my program.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more string based

```
def dec(s):
    s = s.rstrip('.')
    if(s.find('.') == -1): 
        return s
    else:
        i = s.find('.')
        return s[:i] + '.' + s[i+1:i+3]


print(dec('3.1415'))
print(dec('3'))
print(dec('1234.5678'))
print(dec('1234.5'))
print(dec('1234.'))
print(dec('1234'))
print(dec('.5678'))

3.14
3
1234.56
1234.5
1234
1234
.56
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is something I had in the back of my mind when asking the question and I guess the sort of thing I was going to try if I couldn't get a more elegant number-based solution.